# Delphi: JEDI TrayIcon hides all frames. Bug

Tags: delphi, frames, trayicon, jedi

I have a frame, two buttons and a **JEDI TrayIcon** (TJvTrayIcon, Version 3.40). Delphi XE.

The first button:

```
Frame11.Visible := true;
```

Second:

```
Frame11.Visible := false;
```

When I try to minimize a window -> restore it from a system tray -> click the "Visible:=false" button and then "Visible:=true" = the frame doesn't appear.

A problem is in `[tvAutoHide]` of Visibility of TJvTrayIcon.

I don't see this problem in a new project, but I have in an old one. I cannot understand why it happens and how to prevent it.
Please see my problem project: http://www.filedropper.com/trayicon

Thanks for help!

Comment: If I was trying to solve this I would gradually remove bits of code until the program started behaving. That would identify the problem code. Could you try doing this?

Comment: Sure, I've removed everything. Check my code please, there is nothing.

Comment: OK, so which bit of code makes the difference the code working and not working?

Comment: None, only `Frame11.Visible := true;` and `Frame11.Visible := false;` left! I don't know what causes the problem... apparently not my code.

Comment: I can't reconcile these comments with "I don't see this problem in a new project, but I have in an old
one."

Comment: I had the old project with the problem, I deleted all code (only 2 strings left). There is no problem in a blank project.

Comment: @maxfax - You're probably not setting `tvAnimateToTray` option in a new project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, there's a bug in the `TJvTrayIcon`. When `AnimateToTray` is in `Visibility` options, it does not restore `Application.ShowMainForm` and `Application.MainForm.Visible` states. It shows the window but 'Visible' is still false for your form after you restore it. That leads any attempt for showing hidden controls to fail since their parent is *seemingly* not showing.

Fixing the bug is beyond the scope of this answer. For a workaround put:

```
Application.ShowMainForm := True;
Visible := True;
```

somewhere. For a quick test, in your Button1 click event before showing the frame. But you would want to put it after the main form is restored for not having other side effects.